# Python server write UTF to Java client over socket

Tags: java, python

I am making a Python server for a third-party Java client. The client uses `DataInputStream.readUTF()` and I was wondering how I could write a UTF in Python over a socket to Java.

Server current code:

```
import socket
port = 3687

def main():
    print("Running on port " + str(port))
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("", port))
    s.listen(1)
    c, a = s.accept()
    c.send(str(unichr(1))) #Packet id
    c.send("Hello".encode('utf-8')) #MOTD
    c.send(str(unichr(0)) + str(unichr(3))) #Players
    c.close()
    s.close()
    print("Complete")

main()
```

Client code (Can't be changed):

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.setKeepAlive(false);
s.setSoTimeout(3000);
s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address,port), 3000);
s.getOutputStream().write(0);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
if(in.read() != 1)
    throw new Exception("Invalid response");
serverMOTD = in.readUTF());
playersOnline = in.readChar();
s.close();
```

The client crashes when it reads the UTF with an error of:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:178)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:592)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)
```

Comment: Implement what it says in DataOutput.writeUTF(). You won't find it easy but the specification is perfectly clear. What's the question here?

Comment: @EJP I want to write utf from a python server to a java client.